# Next 3 not scrolling to saved position on browser back

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm having an issue with Nuxt3 where on browser back button press, the window isn't cropped to the saved position. In this code below, when I log the saved position, on back action it logs the correct vertical scroll value, but the scroll to that position isn't activated on back.

I have enabled smooth scrolling to anchor links using this code in the `app/router.options.ts` file with this code

```
import type { RouterOptions } from '@nuxt/schema'

export default <RouterOptions> { 
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
        console.log(savedPosition);
        return savedPosition
    } else if (to.hash && to.path == from.path) {
        const el = document.querySelector(to.hash);
        return { top: el.offsetTop, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" };
    } else {
      return { 
        top: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you click on the back button, it's the browser back button?
In this case it's expected because the browser reload it's not a behaviour inside your app.

Comment: No because it’s a nuxt app. When I click the browsers back button I can see the correct scroll value pop up in the console from the log but it just doesn’t trigger the scroll